# Replace *\n.*\n= using sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

Given text in file is as follows:

```
oldValue
=null* 
persistedObjectId
="STRAN-2019-10420"* 
persistedObjectVersion
=0* 
propertyName
="Status"* 
uri
="/oms/salesOrder/saveSalesOrder"
```

How do i replace everything between '*' and '=' (not the other way round)?
I unsuccessfully tried using

```
sed 's/\*\n.*\n=//g' filename.txt
```

Comment: Please show the expected result. Can the problem be reworded as "remove all lines that don't start with `=` or end with `*` and strip the leading `=` and trailing `*`? Please [edit] your question to add more information. Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `sed` works line-by-line, so your multi-line pattern will never match. If you are using GNU `sed`, you can use option `-z` to work with all lines in the same buffer:

```
sed -z 's/\*[^=]*=//g' filename.txt
```

Note that I also changed your code: Because the `*` is greedy, it will eat up all lines up to the last `=` when using `.*`, so I changed it to `[^=]*` which will stop at the next `=`.

Without option `-z`, you need to collect the whole file in one buffer by yourself. I typically collect everything in the hold space and exchange hold space and pattern space for the last line:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\*[^=]*=//g'
```

- `H` appends each line to the hold space
- `1h` overwrites the hold space with the current line to avoid adding a newline to the start of the file
- `$!d` deletes each line but the last one and stops further processing for those lines
- `x` and following are executed for the last line only and exchanges both spaces, so the whole file, that was collected in hold space, is now in the pattern space

Comment: Thank you @Philippos. It worked like a charm. Can you please explain the meaning of every character in [^=]*

Comment: `[`...`]` in a regular expression is used to give a collection of characters to be matched, so `[ab]` will match either `a` or `b`. `^` inverts the match, so `[^ab]` will match any character except for `a` or `b`. The `*` means any number or occurences of the element before, so `[^=]*` will match any string of characters as long as it's not a `=` sign. For more details, plese read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended